# Run same function in parallel with different input files and different outputfiles

Tags: python, io, multiprocessing

I have a method in python that takes a large file as an input and return a file as an output.

I want to parallelize the process using multiprocessing (Pool). So for that I split the input file to let say 3 smaller files.

My method:

```
     def A(self, input_file):
         ....
         ....
         ....
         output_file = out.txt #(path to output file)
         ....
         ....
         output_file = do_smth(input_file)
         return output_file
```

The way I want to gain performance through multiprocessing:

```
         splited_input_file = split_file(input_file)
         p = Pool(5)
         list_of_output_files = p.map(A, splited_input_file[0], splited_input_file[1], splited_input_file[2])
         output_file = concatenate_files(list_of_output_files)
```

Now, my concern is since the output file in A (out.txt) is the same when the multiprocessing is running how the list_of_output_files will be distinguished and I concatenate them into a file as final output file. Any suggestion? Basically in the example above the file is divided into 3 files (splited_input_file[]) and expect 3 output files as well (list_of_output_files) but the path in A is the same (out.txt) and they might get accessed at the parallel processes and may mess up or loose some data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the final output file to be in order (i.e. something like splited_input_file[0] + splited_input_file[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) + splited_input_file[2])? If so, you could define a function that takes the data you want to write and the output file name as parameters, then have multiprocessing run it 3 times with different file names to avoid the 3 processes from accessing the same file in parallel.

An additional thing to note is that you can actually use [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) for less overhead than multiprocessing since this is an I/O bound process (reading writing files) and python releases the GIL for these.

Comment: No, it is ok if the final output file is not in order. The issue is the out.txt is changed inside the method that I need to parallelize it, and not sure how to handle this.